# SSRS: Top 5 Weekending

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a report the I need to display the top 5 XFRS using the Matrix, but it is not displaying the top 5 on some Weekending.  The Matrix below the chart is displaying the Top 5 XFRS, but on my detail report it is not displaying the Top 5 for weekending for 7/22,7/29,8/5 & 8/12.  I used the FILTER to set up the Top X.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple filters, try adding your "Top 5 Transfer Source" dimension to context on the filter shelf (right click on the pill, select 'add to context'). This will cause Tableau to issue that query first.

Comment: I apologize, but I labeled my title incorrectly.  This is for SSRS not Tableau. :(